# codeception laravel seeResponseContainsJson don't match

Tags: laravel-4, phpunit, codeception

I've got frim the server this response :

> )]}', {"success":0,"errors":{"error":["Invalid username or
>   password."]}}

and I'm not able to do work seeResponseContainsJson
I've tried with:

```
public function invalidUserShouldBe200AndJsonTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('To see a 200 status code and a json response');
        $I->sendAjaxPostRequest('/api/v1/signin',array('email'=>'user@users.com','password'=>'user'));
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs('200');
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();
        $I->seeResponseContainsJson(array('errors' => array('error' => array('Invalid username or password.'))));
    }
```

but I've got

> I see response contains json {"errors":{"error":["Invalid username or
>   password."]}}

and it's the same also if the response is

> {"success":0,"errors":{"error":["Invalid username orpassword."]}}

mmm should be something wrong if I try

```
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
dd($I->grabResponse());
```

seeResponseIsJson give me a green bar but grabResponse get me "" :(

### my test

```
use \AcceptanceTester;

class SessionControllerCest
{

    public function _before(\AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('Grab the XSRF-TOKEN cookie value');
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $text = $I->grabTextFrom('body > div > script');
        $chunks1 = explode("\n", trim($text));
        $chunks2 = explode("=", trim($chunks1[1]));
        $cookieValue = rtrim($chunks2[2], ';"');
        $I->setCookie('XSRF-TOKEN',$cookieValue);
        $I->setHeader('X-XSRF-TOKEN',$cookieValue);
    }

    public function _after()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function invalidUserShouldBe200AndJsonTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('To see a 200 status code and a json response');
        $I->sendAjaxPostRequest('/api/v1/signin',array('email'=>'user@user.com','password'=>'sentryuser'));
        $I->seeCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs('200');
        $I->seeResponseIsJson();// until here green bar
       // dd($I->grabResponse()); // empty string
        //$I->seeResponseContainsJson(array('success' => 0,'errors' => array('error' => array('Invalid username or password.'))));

        $I->seeResponseContains(""); // red bar 
    }
}
```

I set like that in _before because of Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection
it's like

```
Route::filter('xhr', function()
{
    if(!Request::ajax()){
        return Response::make('Not Found', 404);
    } 

});

Route::filter('xsrf', function()
{
    if((!isset($_COOKIE['XSRF-TOKEN']) || is_null(Request::header('X-XSRF-TOKEN'))) || ($_COOKIE['XSRF-TOKEN'] !== Request::header('X-XSRF-TOKEN'))){
        return Response::make('Not Found', 404);
    }
});
```

### the route

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'xhr|xsrf'), function() {
    /* Session */
    Route::post('signin', array('as' => 'session.store', 'uses' => 'App\Controllers\SessionController@store'));
});
```

### DEBUG

There is something wrong if I comment the _before block
trying to send a cUrl request like:

```
curl -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -d "email=user@user.com" \
-d "password=mysentryuser" \
http://lama.io/api/v1/signin
```

I get

> {"success":0,"errors":{"error":["Invalid username or password."]}}

but when I run this

```
// tests
    public function invalidUserShouldBe200AndJsonTest(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('To see a 200 status code and a json response');
        $I->sendAjaxPostRequest('/api/v1/signin',array('email'=>'user@user.com','password'=>'mysentryuser'));
       // $I->seeCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
        $I->seeResponseCodeIs('200');
       //$I->seeResponseIsJson();// until here green bar
       //dd($I->grabResponse()); // empty string
       $I->seeResponseContainsJson(array('success' => 0,'errors' => array('error' => array('Invalid username or password.'))));

        //$I->seeResponseContains(""); // red bar 
    }
```

I got

> I see response contains json {"success":0,"errors":{"error":["Invalid
>   username or password."]}}

so may be something wrong but WHAT !

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the last line of your test as follows:

```
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(array('success' => 0, 'errors' => array('error' => array('Invalid username or password.'))));
```

since that is the JSON that your response contains.

Comment: thanks for the reply but if I try to check like $I->seeResponseIsJson();
dd($I->grabResponse()); I get an empty string :(

Comment: Are you using Codeception 1.x or Codeception 2.x?

Comment: I'm using 2.x version

Comment: Can you try `grabDataFromJsonResponse` to see if that gives you something? If not, then your response is empty.

Comment: Give me an error but as I pointed out in my first comment  grabResponse get me an empty string but it's the same if I try to put ie exit('Help me') in the controller action ...

Comment: Ah, so then we would need to see your controller code. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: I was actually referring to your controller method itself: `App\Controllers\SessionController@store`. Can you add that instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57901/discussion-between-lowerends-and-whisher).